# Making fractions cancel

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

I have an equation that Mathematica really wants to display as
$$\frac{1}{4\pi G} \bigg( 4\pi G A + 4\pi G B\bigg)$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some terms and $G$ a constant.

No amount of `Apart`, `Simplify`, `Cancel`, `Factor`, or anything, will make Mathematica cancel the $4\pi$ on the top and bottom.

What do I need to do to get rid of that?

(It would take of several pages to reproduce the calculation that leads to this, and I have no idea why the $4\pi$ is there in the first place so I couldn't give a simpler exampel.)

---

Update: Let's try this.  I have a very complicated function

```
myFunction[orderG_][xx_?VectorQ]:= 
  Normal@Series[16 Pi G * complicatedFunction[orderG][xx]
   + evenMoreComplicatedFunction[orderG][xx],{G,0,orderG}]
```

As it appears in my code, this function is actually a matrix, but treat itas a scalar to demonstrate.  Later on, I calculate

```
txyz = {t,x,y,z}
delbTab = Sum[ D[c^4/(16 Pi G) myFunction[2][txyz],txyz[[a]]], {a,1,4}]
Normal@Series[delbTab, {c,\[inf],1}]
```

This leads to a term with a factor $\frac{1}{4\pi G}$, then all terms inside the parentheses with their own factors of $4\pi G$. (The factors of $4\pi G$ in the second term is due to its definition)

---

Here is the `FullForm` output:

```
    HoldForm[MatrixForm[Times[Rational[1,4],Power[G,-1],Power[Pi,-1],Plus[Times[4,G,Pi,v3,\[Rho]Star,Derivative[List[0,0,0,1]][v1]],Times[4,G,Pi,v1,\[Rho]Star,Derivative[List[0,0,0,1]][v3]],Times[4,G,Pi,v1,v3,Derivative[List[0,0,0,1]][\[Rho]Star]],Times[4,G,Pi,v2,\[Rho]Star,Derivative[List[0,0,1,0]][v1]],Times[4,G,Pi,v1,\[Rho]Star,Derivative[List[0,0,1,0]][v2]],Times[4,G,Pi,v1,v2,Derivative[List[0,0,1,0]][\[Rho]Star]],Times[4,G,Pi,Derivative[List[0,1,0,0]][P]],Times[8,G,Pi,v1,\[Rho]Star,Derivative[List[0,1,0,0]][v1]],Times[4,G,Pi,Power[v1,2],Derivative[List[0,1,0,0]][\[Rho]Star]],Times[Derivative[List[0,0,0,2]][\[CapitalPhi]],Derivative[List[0,1,0,0]][\[CapitalPhi]]],Times[Derivative[List[0,0,2,0]][\[CapitalPhi]],Derivative[List[0,1,0,0]][\[CapitalPhi]]],Times[Derivative[List[0,1,0,0]][\[CapitalPhi]],Derivative[List[0,2,0,0]][\[CapitalPhi]]],Times[4,G,Pi,\[Rho]Star,Derivative[List[1,0,0,0]][v1]],Times[4,G,Pi,v1,Derivative[List[1,0,0,0]][\[Rho]Star]]]]]]
```

Applying operations like

```
(%*4/(G^-1*Pi^-1))
```

or

```
Distribute[%, 4 Pi G]
```

to the output leads to even more absurd output
$$4\pi G \frac{1}{4\pi G}\bigg(4\pi G A + 4\pi G B\bigg),$$
where $A$ and $B$ are the functions and $G$ is a parameter.

Comment: `Factor[1/(4 Pi) (4 Pi F + 4 Pi G)]` works for me (so does `Simplify`), so the problem is with your code, which you have not shared. :/

Comment: I tried to put it in, and the website complained :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatrixForm` is causing the your problem. `MatrixForm` is a wrapper for pretty-printing output and blocks all computation on its argument including any attempt at simplification. Without the wrapper

```
Times[Rational[1, 4], Power[G, -1], Power[Pi, -1], 
  Plus[
    Times[4, G, Pi, v3, ρStar, Derivative[List[0, 0, 0, 1]][v1]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, ρStar, Derivative[List[0, 0, 0, 1]][v3]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, v3, Derivative[List[0, 0, 0, 1]][ρStar]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v2, ρStar, Derivative[List[0, 0, 1, 0]][v1]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, ρStar, Derivative[List[0, 0, 1, 0]][v2]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, v2, Derivative[List[0, 0, 1, 0]][ρStar]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][P]], 
    Times[8, G, Pi, v1, ρStar, Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][v1]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, Power[v1, 2], Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][ρStar]], 
    Times[Derivative[List[0, 0, 0, 2]][Φ], Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][Φ]], 
    Times[Derivative[List[0, 0, 2, 0]][Φ], Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][Φ]], 
    Times[Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][Φ], Derivative[List[0, 2, 0, 0]][Φ]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, ρStar, Derivative[List[1, 0, 0, 0]][v1]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, Derivative[List[1, 0, 0, 0]][ρStar]]]] // Simplify
```

gives

[image: results]

Answer (score 3):

For

```
expr = HoldForm[MatrixForm[Times[Rational[1, 4], Power[G, -1], Power[Pi, -1], 
  Plus[Times[4, G, Pi, v3, ρStar,  Derivative[List[0, 0, 0, 1]][v1]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, ρStar, Derivative[List[0, 0, 0, 1]][v3]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, v3,  Derivative[List[0, 0, 0, 1]][ρStar]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v2, ρStar,  Derivative[List[0, 0, 1, 0]][v1]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, ρStar,  Derivative[List[0, 0, 1, 0]][v2]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, v2, Derivative[List[0, 0, 1, 0]][ρStar]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][P]], 
    Times[8, G, Pi, v1, ρStar, Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][v1]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, Power[v1, 2], Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][ρStar]], 
    Times[Derivative[List[0, 0, 0, 2]][Φ], Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][Φ]], 
    Times[Derivative[List[0, 0, 2, 0]][Φ], Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][Φ]], 
    Times[Derivative[List[0, 1, 0, 0]][Φ], Derivative[List[0, 2, 0, 0]][Φ]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, ρStar, Derivative[List[1, 0, 0, 0]][v1]], 
    Times[4, G, Pi, v1, Derivative[List[1, 0, 0, 0]][ρStar]]]]]];
```

you can also use

```
Simplify[expr[[1, 1]]]
```

[image]

and

```
% == Simplify[ReleaseHold[expr][[1]]] == 
  Expand[expr[[1, 1]]] == Expand[ReleaseHold[expr][[1]]]
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FullSimplify[1/(4 Pi) (4 Pi f + 4 Pi g)]
f+g
```

Now that you have placed your code in the question it's easy to see the problem: the MatrixForm and HoldForm expressions. Remove all MatrixForm commands and HoldForm commands. Taking your FullForm output and removing these two leading commands allows it to simplify automatically. MatrixForm is a formatting command and causes simplifications not to work. HoldForm tells it not to change the form (i.e., don't simplify).

Comment: If I copy the output and do that, then it simplifies.  If I try to run cancel on the input expression, then it refuses to, and calls to `FullSimplify[%]` do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to cancel 4Pi, but not G, do you? If yes, there is an easy way.  Here is your expression:

```
expr = 1/(4 \[Pi] G)*(4 \[Pi]*G*A + 4 \[Pi]*G*B)

(*   (4 A G \[Pi] + 4 B G \[Pi])/(4 G \[Pi]) *)
```

Try this:

```
expr /. \[Pi] -> 1/4

(* (A G + B G)/G  *)
```

Have fun!